# can we pass function body as a parameter (in callback functions) to URL Query-string?

Tags: javascript, url, query-string

There is a website that has multiple requests and responses , one of them is like this:

https://xxx.hhhh.com/someResult?Type=customsectors&jsoncallback=

and i know how the JS callback function is being called.

i need to know that whether:

1. is there any way to modify that JS file ?

OR

2. is it possible to manually write callback function inside query string like this:

```js
https://xxx.hhhh.com/someResult?Type=customsectors&jsoncallback=
{
function (ojr) {
            var res = new Object();

            res.symbolinfo = RlcServices.PopulateSymbolInfo(ojr.symbolinfo, appendFullDetails);
            res.symbolinfo.IsAti = res.symbolinfo.NSCCode.indexOf("IRO2") >= 0 || res.symbolinfo.NSCCode.indexOf("IRO4") >= 0;

            var queueInfo = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < ojr.symbolqueue.Value.length; i++) {
                queueInfo[i] = {};
                queueInfo[i].BestBuyLimitPrice = ojr.symbolqueue.Value[i].BestBuyPrice;
                queueInfo[i].BestSellLimitPrice = ojr.symbolqueue.Value[i].BestSellPrice;
                queueInfo[i].BestBuyLimitQuantity = ojr.symbolqueue.Value[i].BestBuyQuantity;
                queueInfo[i].BestSellLimitQuantity = ojr.symbolqueue.Value[i].BestSellQuantity;
                queueInfo[i].NumberOfOrdersAtBestBuy = ojr.symbolqueue.Value[i].NoBestBuy;
                queueInfo[i].NumberOfOrdersAtBestSell = ojr.symbolqueue.Value[i].NoBestSell;
                queueInfo[i].NSCCode = ojr.symbolqueue.Value[i].NSCCode;
                queueInfo[i].Place = ojr.symbolqueue.Value[i].Place;
            }
            res.symbolqueue = queueInfo;

            fnCallback(res);
        }
}
```

and i need to change the for loop number here. is it possible or i can't do anything and:
"It is what it is !!!"?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to pass the name of a function to the `jsoncallback` parameter. 

I don't understand your second question regarding the "for loop number". Could you please clarify and demonstrate the problem with examples?

Comment: If you know how a JSONP callback works, you should already know the answer to your question. No, you can not change anything in the script via the `jsoncallback` parameter. You can only "call" a predefined function. Nothing more.

Comment: @jimmysumshugar the example is inside the question, i don't how to say it differently!

Comment: probably (i mean certainly) @Andreas is right i didn't understand the JSONP properly and the hack i want to do is almost virtually impossible.